# Angular Js linking a controller to a route doesn' work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller, routes

I watching an Angular course on codeschool and it say that there are two way to link a controller to a route
The first one is declaring the controller inside the route like this:

```
angular.module('NotesApp')
    .config(function($routeProvider){
        $routeProvider.when('/notes', {
            templateUrl:' templates/pages/notes/index.html',
            controller: function(){.....}           
        })
```

the second way is to create a new file and then, over there, declare all the methods associate to that controller. After this have been done, we have to associate the controller to the route, like this.

```
angular.module('NotesApp')
    .config(function($routeProvider){
        $routeProvider.when('/notes', {
            templateUrl:' templates/pages/notes/index.html',
            controller:'NotesIndexController', 
            controllerAs:'indexController'          
        })
```

This controller, I've made, import some data using an ajax call from a json file but it doesn't work well. I have to use this controller inside an HTML file

this is the controller

```
angular.module('NotesApp').controller('NotesIndexController',['$http', function($http){
    var controller = this;

    controller.notes = [];

    $http.get('notes.json').success(function(data){                     
        controller.notes = data;
    })
}]);
```

This is the HTML code

```
<a ng-repeat="note in indexController.notes" ng-href="#/notes/{{note.id}}">
                <div class="col-md-3 fixHeight" >
                    <h4>Id: {{note.id}}<h4>
                    <h4>Title: {{note.title}}</h4>
                    <h4>Description: {{note.description}}</h4>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
```

the html should import all note stored inside the controller.notes array and display all it but it seems like the html doesn't recognize the controller and does't import anything.

The code works just if I declare inside the HTMl the controller I have to use like this:

```
<div ng-controller="NotesIndexController as indexController">       
            <a ng-repeat="note in indexController.notes" ng-href="#/notes/{{note.id}}">
                <div class="col-md-3 fixHeight" >
                    <h4>Id: {{note.id}}<h4>
                    <h4>Title: {{note.title}}</h4>
                    <h4>Description: {{note.description}}</h4>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
```

My question is. If I declare the controller inside my route why I should declare it also in my HTML?

Comment: you actually don't need to declare that in html. can you please provide jsfiddle or plnkr so that it helps to debug the issue

Comment: check this plnkr and see if you are manking any mistake. http://plnkr.co/edit/aFFU726uoD5i9Hq83x3N?p=preview

Comment: hello, i saw your code but I didn't understand where's my error. Here is the plnkr link of my code. Hope you can help me: http://plnkr.co/edit/QcxT3Ht1N81N3T69rgiz?p=preview

Comment: There are two things wrong with your plnkr implementation, change the template url to 'notes.html' and your GET url to 'notes.json'

Answer (score 1):

Ok thanks everybody, I figured out what was the problem. This is the complete route.js file

```
angular.module('NotesApp',["ngRoute"])
.config(['$routeProvider',function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider.when('/notes', {
        templateUrl:'templates/pages/notes/index.html',
        controller:'NotesIndexController', // I have to declare the controller inside the template to make it work
        controllerAs:'indexController'          
    })  
    .when('/users',{
        templateUrl: 'templates/pages/users/index.html'
    })
    .when('/',{
        templateUrl: 'templates/pages/notes/index.html'
    })
    .when('/notes/:id', {
        templateUrl:'templates/pages/notes/show.html',
        controller:'NoteShowController',
        controllerAs:'showController'
    })
    .otherwise({redirectTo:'/'});
}]);
```

The problem was the line:

```
    .when('/',{
    templateUrl: 'templates/pages/notes/index.html'
})
```

instead, to load my controller should have been

```
        .when('/',{
    redirectTo: '/notes'
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Please find [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/ghZzuUAmOAvz8CKN3u3u?p=preview) working plunk with your code

```
angular.module('NotesApp',  ["ngRoute"])
.config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider.when('/', {
        templateUrl:'main.html',
        controller:'NotesIndexController', 
        controllerAs:'indexController'          
    })
})
angular.module('NotesApp').controller('NotesIndexController',['$http', function($http){
   var controller = this;

   controller.notes = [];

  $http.get('data.json').success(function(data){      
    console.log(data)
    controller.notes = data;
})
```

}]);